# Finite representations of the Euclidean Group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

What are the finite dimensional indecomposable representations of the special Euclidean group in three-dimensions, SE(3)? To clarify, I'm asking about the group
$$SE(3) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} R&x \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix} \left|R\in SO(3), x\in\mathbb{R}^3\right.\right\}$$
which is the group of translations and rotations of three-dimensional Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

The complete set of the irreducible finite dimensional representations of SE(3)
is 
$$D^{(l)}(R|x)=D^{(l)}(R)\qquad (l=1,2,\dotsc),$$ 
i.e., the $2l+1$ dimensional representations of SO(3), with identity associated to translations. All other irreducible ones are infinite dimensional.

Comment: Can you give a reference for this result ?